# What solution should I use for a backend of an iOS app to store and stream video (like Instagram for example)?

Tags: ios, video, stream, backend

I'm working on an app that will record video and upload it on a server.
The app shoud also to be able to stream this video.
I don't know what backend solution I should use to do it. 
I looked at Azure Media but it's to great.
Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm afraid you are about to learn the rules of Stack Overflow the hard way when this question gets shut down. This community is pretty strict on broad questions like this that have nothing code-related.

Comment: Azure will work fine with iOS, but I still feel strange about having a Microsoft backend with an Apple app. Too much corporateness for one project. I think you should look into [Parse](https://parse.com/products), it's a backend made for easy integration with iOS. They have a lot of nifty products that will minimize your development time if this is your first time around. A Vine-type app like you're talking about is a pretty complex project, so make sure you know what you're up against if you're new to this.